# How can I get the color 'black,grey and white' in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I'm drawing a density plot,and I used the command of 'ColorFunction',but failed to get the color 'black,grey and white' as the paper.The pictures are as follows:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you try? It should be simple as `ColorFunction -> GrayLevel`.

Comment: `ColorConvert[..., "Grayscale"]`

Comment: Oh,right!Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can*** use the option `ColorFunction`.

Here is an example taken from the documentation of [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html)

```
DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Yeah,I got it.Thanks.

Comment: And one more question: How to set the coordinate interval?

Comment: @KarryMa. That's new question as should be posted as such.

Answer (score 0):

I often use PlotTheme -> "Monochrome" for all kinds of plots :

```
DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]